# how to remove a specific language from rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, localization

I have a rails project which is in two languages English and French. I want to remove the french language completely. Is there an easy way to do it ?

Comment: Next time, please indicate what you have already tried.

Comment: there were so many things that I had tried including the one which you have mentioned as the answer that it was not worth writing on SO

Comment: The point is, other spend their precious time trying to help you. We do not know how proficient you are in RoR and what solutions you already considered - and what kind of solutions you are NOT interested in. In that sense, there is no "answer that is not worth writing on SO" - there are only questions that are not written precisely enough or remain unclear. I think it is unique to SO that there are still people who try to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so there was a `filter :locale` in routes.rb and the language was getting detected in the application controller.

Removing the before filters which were setting the language did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Where / How do you set the locale variable? Wherever you do it - can't you just hard-code it to `:en` so that French will never be used?

Comment: If you want to completely remove the language you could, of course, just delete the language file in `config/locale` + all language-specific view files (file.fr.html.erb etc.)

Comment: I was looking for more elegant solution if there is one

Comment: I doubt there is one. What can be more "elegant" than just changing one statement to fix the language?